# why we need Free monad to interpret Action to Future

Tags: scala, scalaz, free-monad

I wrote one example to use scalaz.Free to to map Action to Future, it looks pretty cool. However, I am trying to understand the benefits of it. I hope I can get the answer here. Here is my code snippet

Firstly, I create an Action, which is AST.

```
trait Action[A]

case class GetNumberAction(x: Int) extends Action[Int]
case class GetStringAction(x: String) extends Action[String]
case class ConvertToIntAction(x: String) extends Action[Int]
case class AddAction(x: Int, y: Int) extends Action[Int]
```

Then, I create a class to map Action to ASTMonad by using Scalaz Free and Coyonda.

```
type Functor[A] = Coyoneda[Action, A]
type ASTMonad[A]= Free[Functor, A]

def toMonad[A](action: Action[A]): ASTMonad[A] = Free.liftFC[Action, A](action) 

object ADTMonad {
    def getNumber(x: Int): ASTMonad[Int] = toMonad(GetNumberAction(x))
    def getString(x: String): ASTMonad[String] = toMonad(GetStringAction(x))
    def converToInt(x: String): ASTMonad[Int] = toMonad(ConvertToIntAction(x))
    def add(x: Int, y: Int): ASTMonad[Int] = toMonad(AddAction(x, y))

}
```

At last, I create an Interpreter to interpret Action to Future

```
object Interpreter extends (Action ~> Future) {
    def apply[A](action: Action[A]): Future[A] = {
        action match {
            case GetNumberAction(x) => Future(x)
            case GetStringAction(x) => Future(x)
            case ConvertToIntAction(x) => Future(x.toInt)
            case AddAction(x, y) => Future(x + y)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run it, I can use

```
val chain =  for {
    number <- ASTMonad.getNumber(x)
    str <- ASTMonad.getString(y)
    convertedNumber <- ASTMonad.converToInt(str)
    total <- ASTMonad.add(number, convertedNumber)
    } yield total

chain.runWith(Interpreter)
```

It seems to work and I think I understand this monad and interpreter things. However, I am thinking what is the benefits comparing to the solution if I am using *Future.flatmap* and *map* directly ?

```
for {
    number <- Future(x)
    str <- Future(y)
    convertedNumber <- Future(str.toInt)
    total <- Future(number + convertedNumber)
} yield total
```

The code of using Future flatmap and map looks simpler to me. So back to my questions, do we need to use Free monad to interpret the business logic to Future, since Future has already provided flatMap and map. If it does, can someone give me more concrete example, so I can see the benefits ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A good and motivated example for using free applicative are command-line parsers, let's call the type `CLI[A]`.

A value of type `CLI[A]` means you will get an `A` if you provide command-line arguments (`Array[String]`) and they can be parsed successfully. Now this functionality is isomorphic to `Array[String] -> Either[String,A]` when using `Either` for error handling.

Because you made `CLI` applicative, you can `map` and `apply` (combine) values. You can for example create a `Int` argument `count`, another `Int` argument `count2`, and combine them to a final `sum: CLI[Int]` that holds their sum.

Suppose you apply the computation directly, this yields something that is "only" equivalent to `Array[String] -> Either[String,Int]`. But if you want to create a help text you have to know both initial arguments, and this information is lost.

`Free` to the rescue. With `Free` you can retain the computation graph, which you can use to extract all initial `CLI` values that are directly parsed from the arguments. You can then later run the computation which yields the final value of `sum` by providing the parse results for all initial arguments.

Of course you could implement a special `CLI` that keeps track of all the initial values over computations, but `Free` let's you avoid this extra work.